# How not to change the id of variable when it is substituted

Tags: python

I don't want to change the id of variable. How can I do this?

```
    def _increaseParam(param):
        print id(param)  # -> 140503442059208
        pitch = 50
        param += pitch
        print id(param)  # -> 140503442058968
                         #    different!
```

Comment: This is (basically) impossible.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why is not changing the ID important? You are probably using the object ID for something you really shouldn't use it for.

Comment: I suspect OP tried to do some kind of C-like pass-by-reference shenanigans, discovered it didn't work, fumbled around until they discovered `id()`, and figured they could still make it work [somehow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx).

Comment: `+=` generally works differently between mutable and immutable objects. If the need the `id` to remain the same, `param` needs to be a mutable object. It's probably possible to restructure your calling code to make better sense if you can show it to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the ID is. It's not a property of the variable, it's a property of the object that is assigned to the variable. If you change the object, for example from one number to another, you also change the ID. It is *impossible* to change to a different object without also changing the ID.

You can't even ensure that two identical numbers get the same ID:

```
>>> x = 1234567890
>>> id(x)
37359104
>>> x = 1234567890
>>> id(x)
37344544
```

Comment: impossible - until the memory is recycled. It's important to realise that an `id` you've seen before might later belong to a new object.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler: And in theory, you could probably write some sort of really nasty C extension to modify an immutable value and do what OP wants.  But I imagine CPython might not like that very much, and it's certainly not a Good Idea in any case.

Comment: @Kevin, it's not even that hard with `ctypes` eg. `ctypes.cast(id(param), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))[4] = param + pitch` but now I've gone and broken Python *sob*

Answer (score 1):

The only sure way to do so is to use a mutable object and then mutate it. Since it will be the same object, it will have the same ID.

For immutable objects such as integers and strings, this is all but impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a list and it will not change the objects identity.

```py
def _increaseParam(param):
    param_list = []
    print id(param_list)        # -> 3072758732
    pitch = 50
    param_list.append(param)
    param_list[0] += pitch
    print id(param_list)        # -> 3072758732<br><br>_increaseParam(10)

_increaseParam(10)
```

output:

```
3072758732
3072758732
```